# GET request from a template to a view

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, perl

---

**Summary of problem:**
The way I've done it seems clumsy. To summarise I'm basically trying to pass jquery results to a view. This view then exectutes a subprocess that runs a perl script with the values stored in the jquery variables. This perl script generate the html page (in effect updating what is displayed). Django then needs to wait (like 0.3s) and then refresh the page until the perl script has finished (and a new html file exists). Below is my attempt to do this. It does not work properly though. Any suggestions on what I could do would be greatly appreciated!

---

I've currently got a view that queries a database, populates some drop down tables, and also runs a perl script. The perl script generates an html file based upon the values selected within the dropdown menu. This then updates the page. For all of this, I am using PyCharm as an IDE.

On Internet Explorer 11, The page will update roughly 1/5 times. In the debug console of PyCharm, it will display something like:

```
[30/Apr/2014 10:26:11] "GET /Pass_Rate_by_Platform/?resultValue=cd&modelValue=Ahmed_25 HTTP/1.1" 200 19886
[30/Apr/2014 10:26:11] "GET /Pass_Rate_by_Platform/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19886
```

on each request when it does not work.

When it does, PyCharm displays this:

```
[30/Apr/2014 11:01:52] "GET /Pass_Rate_by_Platform/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19902
[30/Apr/2014 11:01:52] "GET /Pass_Rate_by_Platform/?resultValue=liftforce&modelValue=Ahmed_20 HTTP/1.1" 200 19902
```

So obviously it sometimes it refreshes the page when it shouldn't. Which is evidently the problem for IE.

In Firefox though, firebug tells me that every request I make is sending the same similar Get data. However, this is not being shown in the PyCharm debug section.

Here is the relevant code:

**views.py**

```
def platform_pass_rate(request):
     db = MySQLdb.connect(user='a_user', db='secondary', passwd='something', host='ab-cd')
     cursor = db.cursor()
     cursor.execute('SELECT study FROM study ORDER BY study ASC')
     study_model = [row for row in cursor.fetchall()]
     cursor.execute(
          'SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns where table_name = 
          \'finalvalues\' order by ordinal_position')
     study_result = cursor.fetchall()
     db.close()
     study_models = [i for sub in study_model for i in sub]
     study_results = [i for sub in study_result for i in sub]
     if request.method == 'GET':
        resultVar = request.GET.get('resultValue', 'cd')
        modelVar = request.GET.get('modelValue', 'Ahmed_00')
        subprocess.call(["perl", "static/static/perl/passRateByPlatform.pl", resultVar, modelVar])
        # return HttpResponse(resultVar)
     else:
        subprocess.call(["perl", "static/static/perl/passRateByPlatform.pl", "liftforce", "Ahmed_25"])
     current_url = get_full_path(request)

     return render_to_response("data_form_platform.html", {'our_url': current_url, 
                                                     'study_models': study_models,
                                                  'study_results': study_results})
```

**base.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        {#        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });#}
        var current_url = $('#current_url').text();
        var id = current_url.trim();
        $('#' + id).addClass('active');

        $('#platform_data_form_button').click(function () {
            var selectedResultValue = $('#platform_type_of_result :selected').text();
            console.log(selectedResultValue);
            var selectedModelValue = $('#platform_models :selected').text();
            console.log(selectedModelValue);
            $('#platform_type_of_result').change(function () {
                var selectedResultValue = $('#platform_type_of_result :selected').text();
                console.log(selectedResultValue);
            });
            $('#platform_models').change(function () {
                var selectedModelValue = $('#platform_models :selected').text();
                console.log(selectedModelValue);
            });

            $.get("/Pass_Rate_by_Platform/", { resultValue: selectedResultValue, modelValue: selectedModelValue}, function (response) {
                console.log("workinggggggg");
            });


        });
    });
</script>
```

**Relevant button:**

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-left: -20px" id="platform_data_form_button">
      <a href="/Pass_Rate_by_Platform/" class="btn btn-primary btn-success"></span> Confirm</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of hunting for a new solution I realised that the trailing `/` was the only thing that stopped it from working. Here is the corrected pieces of incorrect code:

**base.html**

Note missing `/` in `href="/Pass_Rate_by_Platform"`

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        {#        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });#}
        var current_url = $('#current_url').text();
        var id = current_url.trim();
        $('#' + id).addClass('active');

        $('#platform_data_form_button').click(function () {
            var selectedResultValue = $('#platform_type_of_result :selected').text();
            console.log(selectedResultValue);
            var selectedModelValue = $('#platform_models :selected').text();
            console.log(selectedModelValue);
            $('#platform_type_of_result').change(function () {
                var selectedResultValue = $('#platform_type_of_result :selected').text();
                console.log(selectedResultValue);
            });
            $('#platform_models').change(function () {
                var selectedModelValue = $('#platform_models :selected').text();
                console.log(selectedModelValue);
            });

            $.get("/Pass_Rate_by_Platform", { resultValue: selectedResultValue, modelValue: selectedModelValue}, function (response) {
                console.log("workinggggggg");
            });


        });
    });
</script>
```

**Relevant button:**

Note missing `/` in `href="/Pass_Rate_by_Platform"`

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-left: -20px" id="platform_data_form_button">
      <a href="/Pass_Rate_by_Platform" class="btn btn-primary btn-success"></span> Confirm</a>
</div>
```

The simplest of errors can be a world of hurt... Hopefully no one else has to go through this ordeal.